# Can I put an Ethernet port in my brick wall?

Tags: brick, ethernet

I want to set up a new network in my home and need one by where my computer is. The problem is I don't know if I can put the ethernet cable and port into the wall without problems. Thanks in advance

Comment: What's on the other side of the brick?

Answer (score 5):

Two issues - cable and port.

### Cable through brick wall

If one end is on one side of a brick wall and the other end is on the other side of the brick wall, drill a hole with a hammer drill and a masonry bit and fish the wire through. A brick wall could be just a couple of layers of brick but often has cinderblock or (as I found when I replaced my oven years ago) all kinds of stone, concrete and junk inside. Ideally you want a bit long enough to go all the way through everything in one shot. Not an easy job, but usually not too hard with a decent drill and bit.

### Cable on surface of brick wall

If you can't easily go through the wall, or you need to run the cable a distance along the wall for other reasons (e.g., the router is 20 feet down the wall **on the same side**) then use a [surface raceway](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=surface%20raceway). Basically, a plastic or metal rectangular tube that you mount on the wall and stick the wire inside. Some people don't like the look, but running cable **inside** a brick wall is not practical so it is either on the surface in a raceway (better than just leaving the wire loose) or through to the other side. If you have a baseboard or molding on the bottom of the wall then you can, depending on the details, either mount a raceway to the baseboard/molding easier than mounting to the brick, or staple the cable directly to the baseboard/molding.

Depending on the type of wall (interior vs. exterior) and where you need to run the cable, and what is underneath the floor, you may be able to drill down through the floor instead and run the cable through the room or crawlspace underneath. However, that is sometimes tricky too depending on the ceiling of the lower level.

### Port

Surface mount the port. Do **NOT** try to cut a hole for a box into the brick - it can be done but is absolutely not worth the effort. You can either use a [standard box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0028CIC8U) designed for mounting on the wall and put a regular Ethernet wall plate on the box, or use a smaller [surface mount port](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079LWWC9N). A standard box has the advantage of allowing for 2 or more ports - easily up to 6, for additional Ethernet or phone or cable TV.

Comment: Good answer, but I would try to avoid the brick entirely.  Just keep everything at floor level.  If there is any kind of baseboard or molding, it may be possible to attach to that.  If it's necessary to go through the wall, look for a non-masonry wall to go through, and run extra cable for the distance.  Look at going through the floor.  Explore WiFi or Powerline options.

Comment: @fixer1234 Agree regarding baseboard/molding - I'll add that. Through the wall - it all depends. I have a big long masonry bit from the first time I needed to do something like this, and I've used it a few times since then - sometimes there is no practical alternative. Through the floor makes sense sometimes, but there are many possible issues. WiFi & powerline work for lots of people, but not everyone, and also depends on if they need to run other cables at the same time (not mentioned in the question but certainly possible).

Comment: @fixer1234 “I would avoid the brick entirely” and “look for a non-masonry wall to go through” is not answering the question. The OP isn’t asking for options to the masonry wall.

Comment: Just occurred to me that it could be just a decorative brick facing on only one side.  In that case, just find a mortar joint that isn't in front of a stud (via stud finder and tape measure on the other side), and drill through that.  Mortar is easy to drill through, but brick takes forever and breaks and chips.

Comment: @fixer1234 That could be, but it could also be like the brick wall my oven & fireplace are in. Or something in between. Agree that drilling through mortar is a LOT easier than drilling through brick.

Comment: @LeeSam, I agree.  I only offered it as an alternative to consider.  The OP may be looking at the most direct way to get from point A to point B, without realizing that the difficulty of going through a brick wall could make a less direct route a lot more attractive.  That's also why I put it in a comment instead of an answer.  :-)